# retrieve back porch (horizontal and vertical) in windows xp

Tags: windows-xp, sync, display, resolution, timing

I need to retrieve specific timing properties from with windows XP modeline to use it in my ubuntu xorg.conf file

I need these properties:

```
Horiz Front Porch, Vert Front Porch, 
Horiz Back Porch, Vert Back Porch,
Horiz Front Active, Vert Front Active,
Horiz Scan (or Sync) Width, Vert Scan Width,
Horiz Sync Polarity, Vert Sync Polarity,
and Pixel Clock.
```

in nvidia Control Panel, the only place i've seen that has some of these details is Display->change resolution->select my current applied custom resolution-> click customize...-> click create custom resolution... -> in there i have the following timing properties:

( in the following, H/V stands for Horizontal & Vertical information )

Active Pixels H/V
Front Porch Pixels H/V
Sync Width Pixels H/V
Total Pixels H/V
Polarity H/V
Refresh Rate
Pixel Clock

So it seems i have almost *everything* i need, except of course back porch H/V

any suggestions how to retrieve this property?

Answer (score 1):

[Extended Display Identification Data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data):

> Many software packages can read and display the EDID information, such as read-edid and PowerStrip for Microsoft Windows and XFree86 (which will output the EDID to the log if verbose logging is on (`startx -- -logverbose 6`)) for Linux and BSD unix.

Also you can get this info on Linux by running `xrandr --verbose`.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW at this late date, the Asker would seem to already have his answer at hand, because Horiz. Back Porch =
Horiz. Total Pixels less Horiz. Active Pixels less Horiz. Front Porch less Horiz. Sync Width. Similarly for
the Vertical numbers, although the term "lines" is usually used in that case instead of "pixels".